# how can I store firebase storage image URL in Realtime database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code is when uploading the image store in firebase storage.

I want this image URL store in the firebase real-time database.

```
 const ref = firebase.storage().ref()
 const date = new Date();
 const name =  date.toLocaleTimeString() + '-' + file.name
 const metadata = {
  contentType:file.type
}
const task = ref.child(name).put(file,metadata)
 task
.then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
 .then(url => {
 const image = document.querySelector('#imageff')
 image.src = url
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try executing the following function:

```
 const ref = firebase.storage().ref()
 const date = new Date();
 const name =  date.toLocaleTimeString() + '-' + file.name
 const metadata = {
  contentType:file.type
}
const task = ref.child(name).put(file,metadata)
 task
.then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
 .then((url) => {
 const image = document.querySelector('#imageff')
 image.src = url

 //Add this URL to Firebase Realtime Database
 firebase.database().ref(`/path/to/location/in/db`).set({
    imageUrl: url
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("URL added in database successfully.")
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
})
```

Make sure the path in `.ref()` is where you want the URL to be in. You can also add more fields along with imageUrl.
Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Here I don't know what is .ref( 'path' ). Can You help me?

Comment: @Kirtan path is where you want to store the data in DB. Can you please add the data manually in Firebase Console and share a screenshot? Then I would be able to explain path using your own example.

Comment: I want to save the URL in my PHP admin table here you can see.  
https://prnt.sc/11z27kj   and 
firebase here https://prnt.sc/11z2j46

Comment: @Kirtan but Firebase Realtime Database stores data like a big JSON tree. So let me give you an example, try this ref: `.ref("/image/url")` and see how the data looks in the console.

Comment: @Kirtan is the issue resolved? If yes then you can accept it by clicking tick icon so others know it has been resolved or please feel free to ask further questions.